# Can a player with cards pass but not declare end of round?

Tags: mage-knight

If I have no cards in my draw pile but I have some in my hand, can I choose to not play any cards but also not declare end of round, or must I declare end of round if I do not play cards? If I must declare end of round in that case, does playing a skill allow me to avoid doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can take a regular turn and do nothing.** However, you **will** end up discarding at least one card.

Everything I reference here is from [these rules](http://wizkidsgames.com/wp-content/uploads/mage/MK_rulebook_ENG_searchable-mar2012.pdf).

### Page 5, "A Player's Turn":

> 2. If your Deed deck is empty at the start of your turn, and if the End of the Round has not been announced yet, you may forfeit your turn and announce the End of the Round. If you do, each other player takes one more turn, and then the Round is over.
>
> b. You must announce End of the Round if your Deed deck is empty and you have no cards in your hand at the start of your turn.
>
> c. If you have cards in your hand, but your Deed deck is empty, it is up to you whether to announce End of the Round, or whether to play your turn.
>
> 4. If you do not forfeit your turn, you have two options: playing a Regular turn, or Resting.
>
> a. **In both cases, you have to play or discard at least one card during or at the end of your turn** (except if your hand is empty but there are still cards in your Deed deck at the beginning of your turn).

If you rest you'll end up discarding cards anyway. During a "regular turn", you don't have to move . As long as you're not in an area with a mandatory action you don't have to do anything. However, this is dealt with later on.

### Page 9, "End of the Turn":

> **7. Drawing new cards:**
>
> a. Before drawing, you may discard any number of non-Wound cards from your hand, if you wish.
>
> **• If you did not play or discard any cards during your turn, you must discard at least one card now.**
>
> d. If you run out of cards in your Deed deck while drawing, stop drawing. Do not reshuffle your discard pile unless you have the Night Tactic card “Long Night” (see that card).

If you want to stall out the end of the game, you can do so for as many turns as you have cards in your hand. Playing a skill doesn't change the fact that you haven't played or discarded any cards at the end of the turn so it won't stall the game out unless it can put more cards in your hand.